# AWK, Unix command: How to match two files using corresponding first column in unix command

Tags: r, linux, unix, awk

I have two file, first  with single column (with repeated IDs), second file is three columns file, first column is IDs which is same with first file BUT unique number, I want to print remaining two columns of second file corresponding to first file IDs.

Example:
First file:

```
IDs
1
3
6
7
11
13
13
14
18
20
```

Second file:

```
IDs Freq    Status
1   1   JD611
2   1   QD51
3   2   
5       
6       
7   2   
11  2   
13  2   
14  2
```

Desired OUTPUT

```
1 1   JD611
3 2 
6
7 2
11 2
13 2
13 2
14 2
18 
20
```

Comment: You can use simple loop. read each line from first file and grep that line from 2nd file.

Comment: Your desired output shows duplicates. To bad, now you can not use `grep -f <(sed '1d;s/.*/^& /' File1.txt ) File2.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next} {print $1, a[$1]}' f2 f1
```

To skip the header line,

```
awk 'FNR==1{next} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next} {print $1, a[$1]}' f2 f1
```

If second file has multiple columns,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c=$1; $1=""; a[c]=$0; next} {print $1, a[$1]}' f2 f1
```

Comment: Thanks, its works, much appreciated, sat, If second file contains multipe coulmn, then what ??

Comment: @mona, Updated answer.